# How can I execute an exe from an application and let it call functions in the application?

Tags: c#, multithreading, scripting, execution

I am writing a C# application that must support scripting, the scripting language being C# itself. The idea is that C# code could be created as text within the application, then compiled and executed, still within the application.

I know how to compile and execute at run-time, as an auxiliary process. But the difficulty is that the running script should interact with the main application, and be able to call some of its internal methods.

Is this technically feasible ?

Comment: Yes it is. I did that some years ago. I didn't have an in-app editor, but scripts would interact with the host. I don't have access to the code any more (changed companies since then) but if I remeber correctly, I was using a scripting engine based on Roslyn.

Comment: Don't know if that's still relevant because the article is really old: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/11/16/the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx, and https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods: my scripts have to interact with the application itself, not with the OS.

Comment: By "Host" I mean scripting host ... this one is a little more recent: https://www.daveaglick.com/posts/roslyn-based-dsls-vs-standard-csharp-scripts

Comment: You can use `Assembly.Load` to load a DLL into the current app and then run code in that assembly using reflection.

Comment: @Enigmativity: interesting. Do you think that this can go to the point that the DLL code can invoke methods in the main application ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust - Yes, easily.